# Ag-Grid scrollbar not working in Angular2 app using IE/Edge/Safari

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, safari, microsoft-edge, ag-grid

I have a problem with usability of Ag-Grid in Angular 2 app, while using IE11/Edge/Safari.
Because nature and quantity of data is sometimes quite big, i need to have vertical and horizontal scrollbar. [Everything works quite well on Chrome and Firefox](http://prntscr.com/eeccg1). But when i test the app in IE .. well .. [things doesn't work as expected](http://prntscr.com/eecdpv) (in this case data fitted in datagrid, this isn't always the case). As you can see, scrollbars aren't there. This wouldn't be a problem since vertical scrolling does work (kinda), but i really need horizontal scrollbar since somethimes there is a lot of data.

Here is the code snippet of my data grid options:

```
this.dataGridOptions = {
        columnDefs: [],
        rowData: [],
        enableColResize: true,
        enableSorting: true,
        rowHeight: 30,
        headerHeight: 28,
        rowSelection: 'single',
        suppressScrollLag: true

    };
```

Thank you for any info